# Is it really possible to change default VRAM of GPU?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, gpu, amd-radeon

I have a laptop with 1 GB VRAM GPU (4,5 GB Total) with an [AMD Radeon HD 7610M](https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-Radeon-HD-7610M.70566.0.html) GPU.

Can the amount of default VRAM on a GPU be changed if there is no option for that in BIOS/Firmware settings?

I have watched many videos but none of 'em did help me to make GTA 5 have more accessible memory.

If there is no option in BIOS on a laptop to change VRAM, can I do it in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

A Registry patch fix exists for Intel GPUs, but **not for AMD**.

I have not tried it (probably because Frogger is too high tech for me) but you can find it at https://www.thewindowsclub.com/increase-dedicated-video-ram-windows-10 which states in part:

> You are not increasing the value for real, but you scale up the amount
>   of VRAM to a value to serve as a substitute for the memory
>   requirements to start the game or an application.

I'd suggest testing performance in-game before and after to make sure this change is beneficial.

--

Follow the below steps to reallocate RAM as VRAM for integrated Intel graphics cards.

Open Run and type `regedit` then navigate to the following path:

**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel**

Right-click on the **Intel** folder. Choose **New** and click on **Key**. Name the key as **GMM**.

Select the new **GMM** folder on the left sidebar.

Right click on the right side of the Window and click on **New** from the drop-down menu.

Increase dedicated Video RAM in Windows 10

Choose the **Dword** (**32-bit**) and name it as **DedicatedSegmentSize**  .

Double click on the **DedicatedSegmentSize** and click on the radio button with option **Decimal** to set the base to *Decimal*.

Enter the number of megabytes of RAM you want to allocate as VRAM in value data. Make sure you type a number within the range from *0* to *512*.

**Save** to apply the changes.

Restart the system.

Comment: Yup, and upvoted accordingly.

Comment: Cool, but we're moving around the Intel regs, are you sure that may work?

Comment: @Arty I was answering the question in general. The first line of the answer stated A Registry patch fix exists for Intel GPUs, _but not for AMD_, so in your case, I am sorry but this will _not_ work.

Comment: So there is technically no way to expand my memory? :,( @K7AAY

Comment: AFAIK, correct.